# How to change key size in existing keystore android

Tags: android-studio, keystore, keytool, android-keystore

Can we change keysize of existing keystore(.keystore) that is used for signing existing app? I want to change it from 1024 to 2048.

If it is not possible then what can be the work-around so that it does not break the app update of existing app.

PS: Don't have any details on how the existing keystore was generated